# Cannot mount 2 windows merged ntfs volumes in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, grub2, mount, ntfs, raid

when my brand new Ubuntu is trying to mount my two hard drives that was merged in windows 7 I get this message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdc1 at /media/luttikon/Media 1: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdc1" "/media/luttikon/Media 1"' exited with non-zero exit status 12: Failed to read last sector (7814049791): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdc1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdc1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

I'm new in Linux/Ubuntu but I know how to use the terminal.

Comment: What does it mean that they were merged in Windows? What's the output of `sudo fdisk -l` - does it recognise an NTFS partition?

Comment: yes it does but it can't be mounted.

Comment: In Windows, turn off hibernation and do a `chkdsk /f x:` where X: is the drive letter of the drive.  If asked to reboot, *reboot back in windows*.
After this, reboot into Ubuntu and in a terminal, try the following commands: `mkdir /media/lutticon/win-drive` and then `mount /dev/sdc1 /media/lutticon/win-drive --fake --verbose --types ntfs` and report back with the output in your question ([edit] your question first!)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY
```

where XY is the name of the drive 
for example sdc1

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.